# Django Syntax Highlighting within POST form

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

In Django 1.8, I have enabled prism syntax highlighting[1] css / js within head section of my base.html template

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/prism.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/prism.js' %}"></script>
```

I have proved this works ok, by pasting in the code tags (below) directly into my html, and it shows up as expected:

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-markup">
        code line text here
    </code>
</pre>
```

The problem that I have, is I wish to add these tags directly into a PostForm (like a user making a blog post, where they want to highlight code examples)

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_ossn', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'website/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

When I do this, it seems the render is messing up the tags and breaking prisms ability to parse the tags out.

This is what I see for view source:

```
pre&gt;<br />&lt;code class=&quot;language-markup&quot;&gt;<br /><br />    code line text here<br /><br />&lt;/code&gt;<br />&lt;/pre&gt;</p>
```

So I maybe wrong here, as I only started learning django since last week, but I have a suspicion the form render / post is breaking the code tags?

Is there any was I can escape / prevent this from happening? Or is something else going on that anyone could advise on a resolution?

[1] http://prismjs.com/download.html

Comment: I think you should take a look at the ’safe’ filter.

Comment: I was reading about the safe filter earlier, but I am not having much luck visualising where I should implement it.  EDIT: That was it <p>{{ post.content|safe|linebreaksbr }}</p>

Comment: There is also an autoescape filter which is able to surround several lines of code. You could use that as well.

Comment: Just been playing with autoescape/escape and safe, but all three are not working well with multiple lines.